# how to pass correct scope to app registration to query the azure management service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-service-principal

I am new to azure and
I am trying a simple thing but not able to figure out how to set the correct scopes for a service principal.
I want to start and stop a ML compute using rest API. In order to do so, I would need the right token.

below are the steps I have taken :

- create a service principal
- created a Oauth query to get the access token

but I get error that

```
  {
     "error": {
         "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience",
         "message": "The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 'api://{<!-- -->{id}}'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'."
     }
 }
```

Now, I am not able to figure out this concept. I have 2 doubts :

1. how to set this scope at the service principal end (in the portal), I dont see any such option and also I am not able to find the documentation.
2. how this access works? even if I give some resource level owner access to a service principal, then do I still have to provide access at scope option of app registration?

Please help in coming out of this issue.

Comment: it is oauth related. how do you get the token in the first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** that: To start/stop a ML compute instance **`https://management.azure.com/`** scope is required not
`api://ClientId`.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application** and added API permission:

[image]

Make sure to grant Admin consent to the Api Permission. As **`user_impersonation`** is a delegated permission, you should make use of Authorization Grant Flow or Implicit Flow to generate the token.

I generated the **Authorization code** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectUri
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectUri
code:code
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can also make use of **Implicit Grant Flow** by running the query like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=RedirectUri&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910
```

Access token will be generated redirecting to your redirect Uri like below:

[image]

Any of the above ways will generate the access token with the **aud** **`https://management.azure.com`** which will allow to start/stop the ML compute instance.

**References:**

[Compute - Start - REST API Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/2022-10-01/compute/start?tabs=HTTP)

[Compute - Stop - REST API Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/2022-10-01/compute/stop?tabs=HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I selected the option under API permission of a service principal -> https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation

After selecting this, I was able to get the token which was needed to work with management.azure.com but I was not able to figure it out how to find this for a service principal.

I must say that I find azure very confusing. I am not able to find the documents and even if I find it, they seem difficult to me.

Probably, after some months of struggle I will find it easy.